# How to query on multiple values in AWS workspaces cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-workspaces

I need to run the `aws workspaces describe-workspaces` command and query for UserName, IP address and WorkspaceId and export to CSV so we can open it in Excel but not sure how to do that. This is what I came up with which does not work, can someone please help? Thanks in advance

```
aws workspaces describe-workspaces --query "Workspaces[*].{WorkspaceId,UserName,IpAddress}" > workspaces.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

There are great examples in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side-advanced).
This query will extract information you need:

`aws workspaces describe-workspaces --query "Workspaces[].{UserName: UserName, WorkspaceId: WorkspaceId, IpAddress: IpAddress}" > workspaces.csv`